# How to set karma config entry through command-line?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I have an automated process to do the following (I have a Jenkins setup to do the following):

1. clone project
2. npm install
3. grunt

The grunt execution fails because of the following error

```
[PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.  

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
```

I found that setting `browserNoActivityTimeout: 10000` in `karma.conf.js` file I solved the problem. But I did it manually (edited the conf file and added an entry).

As I have an automated process, I want to be able to set `browserNoActivityTimeout: 10000` through command-line (example like `npm config set registry=` so that grunt executes properly.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Copy your original `karma.conf.js` into a separate `karma-no-act-timeout.conf.js` file (probably name it better than I did here), drop `browserNoActivityTimeout: 10000` in there and then bootstrap the command lines in your `package.json` file like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "unit-test": "karma start ./config/karma.conf.js",
    "unit-test-no-timeout": "karma start ./config/karma-no-act-timeout.conf.js",
  },
```

Now you can call either the original script using:
`npm run unit-test`
or call the one with browserNoActivityTimeout using
`npm run unit-test-no-timeout` in the command line.

As you noticed, these karma.conf files are in config folder. If your structure differs, update your npm script commands.